# t-Copula Simulations of Bivariate Random Variables: Assigned Correlation != Calculated Linear Correlation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, correlation, multivariate-analysis, copula

I have an n x n correlation matrix of random variables. Consider the following example:

[image: Original Correlation Matrix]

What I would like to do is study the behavior of the joint distributions using a t-Copula with, say, 5 degrees of freedom by manually changing the correlations in the bivariate case. For example, changing the correlation between X1 and X2 from +0.95 to -0.99:

[image: Adjusted Correlation Matrix]

Note that the above is just a representative case I created; the matrix may not be PSD and the correlations may not be internally consistent.

The (potential) issue I'm seeing is that when I look at the joint distributions for X1 and X2 with the adjusted correlation matrix, I am not seeing a -0.99 correlation; rather, I am seeing a small positive correlation (e.g. +0.20). This was not the result I was expecting. **Is there a fundamental statistical reason why this is the case?** Why, by adjusting the correlations between random variables to some desired correlation, the joint distribution produced by a t-Copula with 5 (or whatever) DoF results in a calculated (linear) correlation that is seemingly out of whack? I understand that t-Copulas produce distributions with tail dependency... but I still find it odd that the calculated correlation is the opposite sign of the desired correlation.

*Edit: Example code (Python) below (for a given DoF parameter and correlation matrix input):

corr_input = copy.deepcopy(corr)

np.random.seed(seed)

L=np.linalg.cholesky(corr_input)

results=np.zeros((number,corr_input.shape[0]))

v=(df/sp.chi2.rvs(df,size=number))**.5

v=np.outer(v,np.transpose(np.ones((1,corr_input.shape[0]))[0]))

x = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.zeros((1,corr_input.shape[0]))[0],np.identity(corr_input.shape[0]),number)

y=np.multiply(v,np.dot(x,np.transpose(L)))

results=sp.t.cdf(y,df)

return results

Comment: How are you simulating from the multivariate distribution? Do you have code you can share?

Comment: @Dave Please see my edited post for the code. Maybe this has something to do with the Cholesky decomp and finding the nearest correlation matrix? That is, I change the correlations in the input matrix but maybe these are being altered in the decomposition?

Comment: So you implemented the copula sampling from scratch, right? Debugging your code might be a good first step, though my memory about copula parameters is that they need not coincide with Pearson correlation.

Comment: Just to comment: the Kendall's rank correlation is the one that we get guarantees for usually...